# Rails : how to change resourceful actions parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For standard rails  resourceful actions (say communications controller )

```
  index
  create
  show
  update
```

show has parameter id

```
get /communications/:id
```

route

Is it possible I can have

```
   get /communications/:username
```

for show action?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Surya  Can I pass a `:username` parameter to  show action instead of `:id`  parameter?

Comment: @icn, you can try friendly_id (https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `resources :communications, param: :username` 
For more information visit http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html